# Unable to Tell via Graph if Tenant has Teams Enabled

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Currently, Microsoft Graph does not appear to provide a way of checking whether a tenant has Microsoft Teams enabled.

**Is there way to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

According to your descriptions, you want to check whether a tenant has Microsoft Teams.

There is [a document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams) on how to list Joined Teams. Only the beta version has this interface.

Base on my test, we can use the API like this:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams`

It will list the teams that we joined.